# Jekyll in gulp fails at win32

Tags: gulp, jekyll

I worked on a stationary computer with a 64-bit system - everything was alright.
Now I decided to work on the tablet with a 32-bit system. Moved all project files (without folder `node_modules`), installed node.js, launched comand `npm i`, so in theory, all modules and dependencies should be established by themselves. Before that, of course, globally installed gulp-cli.
sass, jade, js are compiled without problems, which means, gulp and dependence correctly installed.
The problem is that I do not know why I have the error in jekyll task.
On the Internet, I found the solution by adding `exec` instead `spawn` to  childprocess (`child` is `childprocess` in my gulpfile.js). Added - it solved one problem, but there was another error (the current error in question).
Also, some people have same error (as in my question) becouse they forgot to exclude from the jekyll compilation folder `node_modules`. But I rule it in `_config.yml` file:

```
exclude: ["node_modules", "gulpfile.js", "package.json"]
```

And it is not clear what the problem is.
Here is my task [jekyll], in which the error occurs:
var messages = {jekyllBuild: 'Running: $ jekyll build'};

```
gulp.task('jekyll-build', function (done) {
    browserSync.notify(messages.jekyllBuild);
    var pl = process.platform === "win32" ? "jekyll.bat" : "jekyll";
    return child.exec(pl, ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'}).on('close', done);
});
```

But the error itself:

```
[14:55:51] Using gulpfile C:\Web\vostoksisters\gulpfile.js
[14:55:51] Starting 'sync group0:0'...
[14:55:51] Starting 'jade'...
[14:55:51] Finished 'jade' after 44 ms
[14:55:51] Starting 'sass'...
[14:55:51] Starting 'js'...
[14:55:51] Finished 'js' after 6.95 ms
[14:55:53] Finished 'sass' after 2.06 s
[14:55:53] Finished 'sync group0:0' after 2.12 s
[14:55:53] Starting 'sync group0:1'...
[14:55:53] Starting 'jekyll-build'...
[14:55:53] 'jekyll-build' errored after 32 ms
[14:55:53] Error: 1
    at formatError (C:\Users\reall\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:169:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\reall\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:195:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (C:\Web\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
    at C:\Web\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
    at finish (C:\Web\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at ChildProcess.cb (C:\Web\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:29:3)
    at emitTwo (events.js:111:20)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12)
```

Comment: Did you have Jekyll installed ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel, yes. In global and in project with --save-dev flag. In `packages.json` i have `jekyll@3.0.0beta`  to install. On my 64bit computer I have the same `packajes.json`.